# Start rails server in production mode local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency, thin

we have some concurrency issues, that I'd like to reproduce on my machine. On production we have a passenger instance running. To get concurrent request, I tried to start the rails app (**Rails 3.2**) with thin and a threaded option like this:

```
bundle exec thin --threaded -p 3000 --threadpool-size 50 start -e production
```

I also ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to get everything like in production.

However, when I access `localhost:3000` in my browser, I get part of the HTML (it displays), but then the browser runs into a timeout with `GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` and loading of the page stops.

When I stop thin with Ctrl-C, I get the following message multiple times:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: Attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked
```

Anybody an idea, why the browser gets a timeout, or how to get concurrent requests working on a local machine with thin? It would also be no problem to try another server like puma, but a whole apache / passenger installation would be too much.

**Update**

I tried it without the browser, and just do a `curl --verbose http://localhost:3000`. The first time, I get the HTML back:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:3000/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 88748
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< ETag: "d16fa9f8e279774f09c2172988a6d5a6"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< Set-Cookie: _session_id=c23af3cc254b66789b635edfefd4a120; path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Request-Id: 539b87c3916cf6733fc9e91a05c4f8e9
< X-Runtime: 0.488556
< Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 13:33:26 GMT
< X-Rack-Cache: miss
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: thin
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
... (more html)
```

But the second time I run the curl command, it times out:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:3000/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Unfortunately, no errors are written to the thin's output or `log/production.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Completely wild speculative guess... but do you have partial caching enabled in production, and not able to reach the cache server (e.g., memcache or redis) from your local environment? It might (???) explain why the HTML only partly renders.

Comment: No, I'm not using any cache server

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your config so that they point to all your local resources instead of trying to reach the production resources?

What I can think of happening here is that, one of your resource is probably un-reachable. Also try to reduce the log level to debug in config/environments/production.rb